# Standalone Spring Boot Integration Java Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to build a standalone Spring Integration application that has an inbound RabbitMQ based gate way. As the application needs not to handle HTTP requests, I want to make it a runnable Java project (that can be simple run using java -jar). I borrowed this idea after going through a [Spring Batch Guide example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) :-

> Make the application executable
>
> Although batch processing can be embedded in web apps and WAR files,
>   the simpler approach demonstrated below creates a standalone
>   application. You package everything in a single, executable JAR file,
>   driven by a good old Java main() method.

**PROBLEM 1**

How should I start my Spring Boot application ? The Spring Boot Java application must run endlessly until interuppted.

**PROBLEM 2**

Exclude web project nature.
Currently I trying my luck using :-

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
    EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class,
    DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class,
    EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.class })
// THESE excludes are not helping. !!!
public class MyIntegrationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {            
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(
                DelinquencyEngineApplication.class, args)));
    }
}
```

As my classpath has Spring Web MVC jar (indirectly through spring-boot-starter-integration dependency ), trying to run above main method results in this execption:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.hcentive.wfm.delinquency.DelinquencyEngineApplication.main(DelinquencyEngineApplication.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 more
```

How can I completely exclude web project nature ? Tried some excludes on @SpringBootApplication but it didn't help.

**PROBLEM 3**

How should I handle graceful shutdown ?
My application should not end abruptly when someone kills the Java application.

Spring Boot 1.2.3 is used.

Thanks.

Comment: For Problem1 You can make your MyIntegrationApplication to implement CommandLineRunner interface ..

Comment: What should go inside the method of CommandLineRunner interface ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEM 1**

A spring boot application will run until you stop it. It is a standard java application. You can run it using the `java` command

```
java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The main issue will be the packaging. Have a look at :

- [Spring Boot Maven plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)
- [Maven App assembler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/)

**PROBLEM 2**

To exclude the web nature you should use the [`SpringApplicationBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html) builder

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(false).run(args);
```

**PROBLEM 3**

In console mode `CTRL+C` will shutdown gracefully. In daemon mode, the Maven App assembler plugin (which embed [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html)) will output a shell script with start/stop. 
As suggested by Gary, see too [Spring Integration Documentation about orderly shutdown](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/index.html#jmx-shutdown)

Comment: PROBLEM 2 - Trying to run using the builder I am getting :- java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.context.annotation.MBeanExportConfiguration$SpecificPlatform from class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration'  Any idea what may be causing this ? Thanks

Comment: Seems related to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2535). Are you using at least the fix version or above?

Comment: PROBLEM 3: Also see the [Spring Integration Documentation about orderly shutdown](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-shutdown).

Comment: @KumarSambhav with which spring core version? The one pull by spring boot?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: Have you checked your transitive dependencies too? eg. for maven launch a `mvn dependency:tree` and check there is no unwanted resolution

Comment: @NicolasLabrot Yes. I just found that removing spring-batch-integration dependecy fixed the problem. Not sure why spring-batch-integration was causing the problem.

Comment: it should depend on an old Spring version and Maven should have resolved to this version